# Delete Certain String in Text Files Using PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

    //reference text
    foreach (glob("file1.txt") as $filename1) {         
    $file1 = $filename1;
    $line1 = rtrim($file1, "\n");
    $contents1 = file($line1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
    $string1 = implode($contents1); // file_put_contents('google.txt',implode('',$contents1));   
    $array1 = str_split ($string1 );
    $temp = $array1;        
    }

    //fetch from website
    $url ="https://www.example.com/";
    $str = file_get_contents($url);

    $myFile = "file2.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $str;
    fwrite($fh,$stringData);
    fclose($fh);

    foreach (glob("fetch_hLeong.txt") as $filename) {   
    $file = $filename;
    $line = rtrim($file, "\n");
    $contents = file($line,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $string = implode($contents);
    $array = str_split($string);
    $temp1 = $array;
```

}

//compare
$result = array_diff_assoc($temp, $temp1);
if (!count($result))
echo "
File  => MATCH"; 
else 
echo "
File  => NOT MATCH";

?>

So i have this type of code, im going to compare those file1.txt and file2.txt.
Here i put each of the character in text files into an array and i compare it character by character. 
So my problem is, while comparing the code show NOT MATCH, which actually it is match.
The www.example.com has news feed that make it change every second because of that my files show NOT MATCH.

i want to delete certain string which is the newsfeed in the file1.txt so that it wont effect the process. Anyone ?? Thanks for your help .

Comment: cause it's more easier i think to get text file.

Comment: do you care how the files are different, or just that they are?

Comment: i care about changes every character in the text files if its differnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of using file+implode, use file_get_contents
2. You cannot use array_diff here since it compares the contents of the array, not the particular order as you need it
3. Have a look at [PEAR's Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff) for creating textual diffs.